# Your project is using deprecated "rnpm" config that will stop working from next release. Please use a "react-native.config.js" file to configure

Tags: react-native

I'm trying to migrate from rnpm to react-native.config.js using the migration guide.

Unfortunatley when i follow the instructions and write the code below, i try to run it , it says that: **error Unrecognized command "run-ios".**

Did anyone had experience migrating it and could tell me what im doing wrong?

Thanks infront

```
 module.exports = {
  project: {
    ios: {},
    android: {}, // grouped into "project"
  },
  assets: ['./Fonts'], // stays the same
  commands: require('./path-to-commands.js'), // formerly "plugin", returns an array of commands
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.7",
    "axios": "^0.19.2",
    "native-base": "^2.13.8",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.61.5",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-cli": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-dimension": "^1.0.6",
    "react-native-elements": "^1.2.7",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.5.2",
    "react-native-image-slider-box": "^1.0.5",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^2.2.26",
    "react-native-interactable": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.5.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.4.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^0.7.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-view": "^1.0.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.4.0",
    "react-native-sectioned-multi-select": "^0.7.6",
    "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.2",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.2.0",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.14",
    "react-native-typography": "^1.4.1",
    "react-native-ui-lib": "5.4.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^6.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^4.0.10",
    "react-navigation-drawer": "^2.3.3",
    "react-navigation-material-bottom-tabs": "^2.1.5",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.3.6",
    "react-navigation-tabs": "^2.6.0",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.3",
    "react-simple-line-icons": "^1.0.8",
    "redux": "^4.0.5",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.6.2",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.6.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^0.0.7",
    "@types/jest": "^25.1.4",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.19",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.61.15",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "16.9.2",
    "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.5.1",
    "jest": "^25.1.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.59.0",
    "react-native-typescript-transformer": "^1.2.13",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1",
    "ts-jest": "^25.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.6.3"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### To create a react-native.config.js file, you need to follow these steps:

```
•  Create a new file named react-native.config.js in the root directory of your project.

•  In the file, export an object with the configuration options you want. For example, if you want to add custom fonts, you can do something like this:

module.exports = {
assets: ['./src/assets/fonts'], // path to your custom fonts folder
};

•  Save the file and run npx react-native link to link the assets to your native project.
```